# Is their a version of K-clique, fluid communities, and German Newman algorithms that can support directed/weighted graphs?

Tags: python, networking, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I am trying to detect communities in the UK railway network using python, both considering the non-weighted version and the weighted one, and I need to use k-clique, fluid communities, and German-newman algorithms considering weights, and I couldn't figure out how.

I have already done these algorithms but only without considering weights and I successfully did other algorithms considering weights, the weights are representing number of passengers travelling through that link.

I searched for such alternatives of these algorithms to support weight but I couldn't find any.

Comment: If you haven't found an answer, you can ask the question another new stack site: https://or.stackexchange.com/